# Regex to remove [quote= *]something[/quote] or similar from mybb_posts.message

Tags: php, regex, quote, mybb

I must remove from

```
[quote='Joker' pid='478' dateline='1346752283']
Benvenuto N1xx1, ti auguro una buona permanenza!
[/quote]Grazie.
```

everything is inside [quote= ...] * [/quote] and return only "Grazie."

I was returning a MyBB message but I don't need any type of [quote][/quote]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#\[[Qq]uote=(.*?)\[/[Qq]uote\]#s` would match it.

`$newString = preg_replace('#\[[Qq]uote=(.*?)\[/[Qq]uote\]#s', '', $yourString);` Should replace them all with `''`.

(Unless there are nested quotes - but that's an entirely different issue from your current question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $string = "[quote='Joker' pid='478' dateline='1346752283']          
    Benvenuto N1xx1, ti auguro una buona permanenza!            
    [/quote]Grazie.";
    echo preg_replace('/\[quote.*?\].*\[\/quote\]/si','',$string);
    echo "<hr>".preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', "", $string);
```

Working sample: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9n4eii